# Inkscape menus Squares with prohibition signs instead of icons

Tags: inkscape

Could you suggest me a method to get the right icons back in the Inkscape 1.1 menu? As soon as it was installed, many small squares appeared with a prohibition sign inside. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Please edit our post and rephrase a bit (both question and header): it is not a matter of having no icons, but of having a generic fallback icon, and currently this is misleading.

Comment: forgive me I don't understand. in what should I change the question?

Comment: You say there are no icons. In your picture, however, I do see icons, albeit not the correct ones.

Comment: Okay, I'll rephrase the question. no problem